# Corpora for sentence compression

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, resource-request, summarization

I am looking for corpora for sentence compression. I am mostly interested in English, and any type of sentence.

I am aware of:

- https://github.com/google-research-datasets/sentence-compression 
  *Overcoming the Lack of Parallel Data in Sentence Compression*, Katja Filippova and Yasemin Altun, Proceedings of the 2013 Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing (EMNLP '13), pp. 1481-1491. ([pdf](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D/D13/D13-1155.pdf))